# Как отправлять от бота сообщения в разные группы по одному запросу?

Tags: python, telegram, telebot

Всем привет! Есть такой код:

```
import telebot

bot = telebot.Telebot('TOKEN')

def send(message):
    if "Привет" in message.text.lower():
        bot.send_message("@durov", "Привет")
        bot.send_message("@durov2", "Привет")

bot.polling()
```

Суть его работы заключается в том, что когда пользователь в группе пишет слово "Привет", бот тоже пишет "Привет".

В данном случае, он отправляет сразу в две группы, если человек написал "Привет" в группе 1. Но как сделать так, чтобы человек в первой группе писал "Привет" и ему писало: "Добро пожаловать в группу 1", и не отправляло в группу 2 сообщение. А во второй группе, когда человек пишет "Привет", то ему отправляется "Добро пожаловать в группу 2", и соответственно, в первую группу, сообщение не шло. думаю, понятно объяснил)

Для меня, это загадка Жака Фреско. Спасибо!

Comment: Проверять в какую группу пришло сообщение, и отвечать в нее же. Документация в помощь.

Comment: Не нашел такого, по этому и спрашиваю(

Comment: Мда, а вообще существует такая функция? Так и не нашел, спустя 3 часа поиска

Comment: а [тут](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#available-methods) пробовали поискать? и еще вот [тут](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#available-types)

Comment: Да, пробовал, и ещё одному программисту скидывал, и он не нашел

Comment: Значит не судьба, если даже документация и два программиста не справились xD, а надо всего то посмотреть структуру сообщения, найти там идентификатор чата, и посмотреть в доку как именно отправляется сообщение в определенный чат :) но видимо современным программистам такие сложные вещи не под силу xD

Answer (score 0):

```
import telebot

bot = telebot.TeleBot('TOKEN')

@bot.message_handler(content_types='text')
def message_reply(message):
    if 'привет' in message.text.lower():
        chat_info = bot.get_chat(message.chat.id)
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, text=f'Добро пожаловать в чат \"{chat_info.title}\"')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    bot.infinity_polling()
```

Попробуйте, должно работать. Бот будет отвечать в тот чат, где пользователь написал "Привет" и в свой ответ автоматом вставлять название группы. Но работать будет естественно при условии, что боту будут выданы права администратора.

`message.chat.id` это как раз та вещь, которую Вам советовали найти выше. Если грубо - бот смотрит ID чата, откуда пришло сообщение и затем отправляет своё в него же.